# Zepto.js doesn't return false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

I'm trying to bind an event handler to a click function using zepto.js.  Normally in JQuery I can just say return false and the actual click will never go through.  Does Zepto not support this?  And if so, how to get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To duplicate the behaviour of returning false in a jQuery event handler you need to call [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.preventDefault) and [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation).

Comment: $(".class").on(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
});